# Independent variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, independence

Does it has a sens :

Let $X\sim N(0,1)$ and take $Z\sim \text{Log-Cauchy}$ such that $X$ and $Z$ are independant ?

The question is about the independant charactere.
Does the independency depends on the two law we have choosen are any random variable may be defined like that ?

Comment: Independence is a property which does not depend on the law. Two variates with the same law can be dependent as well as independent. It's a property of their joint law(i.e. which encodes the info as to how they behave as a pair) and whether the cdf of the joint variate can be expressed as a product of the individual cdfs or not. This is a very basic but rigorous characterization of independence.